# How to configure database.yml to work in a local environment and in Docker both?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, docker

Let's say some of my Rails colleagues would prefer to develop the app inside their own native local development environment they've setup all by themselves to match their needs, and some of my colleagues would prefer to develop the app run from inside a Docker container that comes along with all necessary tools preinstalled.

Now there's the `config/database.yml` which currently looks like following to match the setup of all the native folks and which is started with `bin/rails db:setup`.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
```

But the Docker folks instead do need the following – most important of all **a different host** – and it would be started with `docker-compose run web bin/rails db:setup`. As the host is different now this `database.yml` wouldn't work anymore for the native folks.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: db
  username: postgres
  password:
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
```

What would be the most convenient or less intrusive way to cover both use cases at once? Can I fetch the host value dynamically? How? From an env variable? From a different database.yml? How to then tell Rails to take this one instead?

Note: The Docker setup basically follows https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use the ENV vars Luke.

`ENV['DATABASE_URL']` is merged with the settings from `database.yml` and takes precedence over the values from file.

To avoid developer wars `database.yml` should only contain the bare minimum of settings such as the adapter, encoding and the default names of the DBs:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
```

Anything else such as hosts, passwords should be set by `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` as this is local configuration - not application configuration. This also is preferable for security reasons as it removes the risk of passwords being leaked with the source code.

See:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
- https://12factor.net/config

Comment: You can also use ERB tags in `database.yml`and spread it into a bunch of seperate env vars but thats a complete waste of time IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Simply **mount** a second, docker-specific `database.yml` from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - ./docker/database.yml:/myapp/config/database.yml # Here we go!
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```